# Find the max $\{\sqrt{n^3}\lg n, \sqrt[3]{n^4}\lg^5n \}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, upper-lower-bounds

*Note: the logs are with base 2 (computer scince question).

Let

$$
f(n) = \max\{\sqrt{n^3}\lg n, \sqrt[3]{n^4}\lg^5n \} = \max\{f_1(n),f_2(n)\}
$$

I want to find which function is the max between the two functions such that the bigger will satisfies:

$$
\exists n_0 \in N, \forall n > n_0: f_1(n) > f_2(n)
$$

### What i tried:

I tried to start with comparing the two functions, hopinf to find the cross point, than just checking what happend after and before the cross point.

Therefore, i try to solve:

$$
\sqrt{n^3}\lg n =\sqrt[3]{n^4}\lg^5n 
$$

Solving this i got to: 
$$
\sqrt[3]{n} = \lg^4n
$$

Maybe i miss something, but i dong know how to solve this...

I would like a hint more than a solution.

Thank you very much for the answers.

Comment: Hint:  just do the division.  What is $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {n^{1/6}}{(\log_2(n))^4}$?

Comment: I thought about something like this, but i think the answer is $\infty$ probably im wrong and not sure why, as polynoms are more dominant than $log$, arent they?

Answer (score 0):

Let's play around with real $x$ to see what we get. Rearranging the equation we have

$$x^{\frac{1}{6}} = \lg^4(x) \implies 2^{x^{\frac{1}{24}}} = x$$

Then move everything to one side and with some rearrangement we get that

$$-\frac{\log 2}{24} = -\frac{\log 2}{24}x^{\frac{1}{24}}\exp\left(-\frac{\log 2}{24}x^{\frac{1}{24}}\right) \implies x = \frac{24^{24}}{\log^{24} 2}W^{24}\left(-\frac{\log 2}{24}\right) \approx 2.04$$

but also we have the two expressions are equal when $x=1$ (a solution we lost when we divided both of the original expressions by $\lg x$). If you would only like a hint stop here. Otherwise I continue the solution below.

---

Since these are the only places the expressions are equal, plug in a nice value of $x\geq 3$, say $x=2^6$:

$$\sqrt{\left(2^6\right)^3}\lg(2^6) = 3\times 2^{10}$$

$$\sqrt[3]{\left(2^6\right)^4}\lg^5(2^6) = 3^5 \times 2^{13}$$

so clearly for $ n > 2$  $$ \sqrt[3]{n^4}\lg^5(n) > \sqrt{n^3}\lg(n) $$

Comment: Your final result is wrong.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter why?

Comment: For large $n$ the function $n^{3/2}\lg n$ is larger. This starts at about $n=1.296\cdot10^{54}$.

Comment: $n^{1/24}\approx \lg n$ when $n=2^{180}.$

Comment: How did you  find that number? @ChristianBlatter

Comment: @W.Wongcharoenbhorn for negative numbers, $xe^x = y$ has two solutions, one given by the principal branch of Lambert W, the other just existing. This big number comes from the non principal solution.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter you're right, the other solution to $ze^z = -\frac{\log 2}{24}$ gives the much larger solution.